# Setting a default DateTime.Now value to save to MongoDB when Document is saved

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am very new to C#, having come from the ruby world, the ruby mongodb driver provided a `created_at` and `updated_at` field for all documents on saving and updating. Unfortunately after searching online it doesnt seem like this is a common thing in c#.

I would like to know how would I default a documents `CreatedAt` field to `Time.Now` when persisting?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoDBConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("mongodb_console");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Person>("person");
            var person = new Person
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                Age = 25
            };
            collection.InsertOne(person);

        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
         public int? Age { get; set; }
        [BsonDefaultValue(DateTime.Now)] // <-- this errors out
        private DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit:

My purpose for asking the question is to prevent myself from having to add a `CreatedAt` field every time I instantiate a new `Person` class object. `CreatedAt` should be automatically set whenever the `Person` class is persisted to MongoDB. One could easily set it every time a document is saved, but that's not very DRY. I am hoping to duplicate functionality that exists in another programming language.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550263/mongo-db-default-timestamp

Comment: that is for mongoose (nodejs) not c# @ChrisCarr

Answer (score 2):

Came across this today,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace NotebookAppApi.Models
{
    public class Note
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public int UserId { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

per the following blog

[Using MongoDB .NET Driver with .NET Core WebAPI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151842/Using-MongoDB-NET-Driver-with-NET-Core-WebAPI)

Comment: When you GET the data from DB, then the model will also set the date time to current date time.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
var person = new Person
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                Age = 25,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
            };
```

Set `CreatedAt` property to `DateTime.Now` also.

Comment: the point is to write less code. this unfortunately does not answer my question. I can set a default string value, by doing `[BsonDefaultValue("abc")]` but it makes no sense that there would be no way to add a Date object by default. I do not want to explicitly add a created at time every time i make a new document.

Comment: You cannot do this with an attribute because they are just meta information generated at compile time. Just add code to the constructor to initialize the date if required, create a trigger and handle missing values in the database, or implement the getter in a way that it returns DateTime.